# Sorting a dict based on one of the multiple values of key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have dict which looks like this

```
t={'Name1':{"Jf":0.89,"Date":"09-10-2018"},'Name2':{"Jf":0.77,"Date":"09-11-2018"}}
```

How do I sort dict in descending based on Jf values. Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code that demonstrates the effort to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `t.items()`, which will returns list of `tuple` object with `key` at `0` index and `value` at index `1`. Use `reverse=True` for descending order,

```
sorted_dict = sorted(t.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['Jf'], reverse=True)
print(sorted_dict)
```

Or if you are just interested in values, you can get `values()` from dict and use `sorted`.

```
sorted_dict = sorted(t.values(), key = lambda x:x['Jf'], reverse=True)
print(sorted_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please edit the first answer, since everybody will want to retain their keys, and also add reverse=True for your second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries don't preserve order, so one can sort it into a list:

```
t = {'Name1': {"Jf": 0.89, "Date": "09-10-2018"}, 'Name2' {"Jf": 0.77, "Date": "09-11-2018"}}
sorted(t.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['Jf'])
```

Which should give the result:

```
[('Name2', {'Jf': 0.77, 'Date': '09-11-2018'}), ('Name1', {'Jf': 0.89, 'Date': '09-10-2018'})]
```

On a side note, you might consider using the datetime library instead of encoding dates as strings; for example:

```
from datetime import date
name1_date = date(2018, 9, 11)
name1_date.month  # Returns 9
```